# History of Sylvester's resultant?

Tags: linear-algebra, ho.history-overview, elimination-theory

Suppose that we have two polynomials that split:
$$\begin{align*}
f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^d a_{d-k}x^k&=\prod_{i=1}^d (x-\lambda_i),\\
g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^e b_{e-k}x^k&=\prod_{j=1}^e (x-\mu_j).\\
\end{align*}$$
Then the following result is often attributed to [James Joseph Sylvester](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Joseph_Sylvester):
$$
\det\begin{pmatrix} a_0 & a_1 & \cdots & a_d && \\ & \ddots &\ddots &&\ddots & \\ && a_0 & a_1 & \cdots & a_d \\ b_0 & b_1 & \cdots & b_e && \\ & \ddots & \ddots && \ddots & \\ && b_0 & b_1 & \cdots & b_e 
\end{pmatrix} = \prod_{i,j} (\lambda_i-\mu_j).
$$

Can someone help me track down the original reference?

Comment: The history of resultants is quite complicated. I am not familiar with non European contributions, but early European work on this is by Stevin 1585, Leibnitz 1683. A good  reference (in French) is the article from the encyclopedia of math see, starting from page 73, https://books.google.com/books?id=5ERtAAAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: This question might be better on https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) of the [Sylvester matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_matrix) first appeared in J. J. Sylvester, Philos. Magazine **16**, 132–135 (1840): [A method of determining by mere inspection the derivatives from two equations of any degree](https://zenodo.org/record/1931489#.X5nTCC9h3OQ).

[image]

The last line is the resultant of the two equations at the top, which vanishes when two roots coincide.
 <sub>I like the "ought to, and is" phrasing...</sub>

---

The Sylvester matrix also appeared in an 1840 publication by Cauchy, who acknowledged the priority of Sylvester:

[image]

<sub>[1876 reprint](http://www.numdam.org/article/NAM_1876_2_15__433_0.pdf) of Cauchy's 1840 article "Mémoire sur l'élimination d'une variable entre deux équations algébriques".</sub>

The name "resultant" originates from

E. Bézout (1764): *Recherches sur le degré des équations **résultantes** de l'évanouissement des inconnues et sur les moyens qu'on doit employer pour trouver ces équations.*
<sub>Research on the degree of equations resulting from the vanishing of unknowns and on the methods one should use to obtain these equations.</sub>

Comment: It's always amazing to look back a few centuries and see how styles of exposition, and even of paper names, change over time.

Comment: Section 9 of [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.03711) has a nice discussion of the history.

Comment: @DrewArmstrong's [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/375119/history-of-sylvesters-resultant/375122#comment951067_375122):  [Penchèvre - Etienne Bézout on elimination theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.03711).